# Create multiple types of custom users in Django 2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.6) and Django(2.1) in which I need to create multiple types of users.

> **Note:** I have searched a lot but very confused about my specific case,
>   so don't mark this duplicated, please!

Here's my scenario:

I need to user types first is `admin` and second is `driver`.
Admin will be able to manage all of the administrative things and also assign orders to the available drivers, and driver will be able to see assigned order when logged into the site.

- **Fetchers** (drivers) Can only complete an order and view orders
  assigned to them. Can receive orders by dispatchers (If logged into
  backend. Otherwise drivers not logged in will not appear for admin to
  see as available drivers)
- **Dispatchers** (admin) Has the ability to assign pending orders to
  drivers that are available. Has the ability to cancel order and void.
  Has the ability to export data from database.
- **Superadmin** (owner) confirms drivers and deletes drivers. Can edit
  driver profile information such as license plate numbers and photos.
  Can create items for grocery and edit information. Can update
  pickup/errand prices such as Fast food pick up $4.00 and add auto
  parts pick up $6.00. Superadmin can also perform anything that admin
  can perform. Superadmin can control any users’ access to dashboard.

So, I need signup and login for both `Admin` and `Driver`, how can I achieve that?

I'm very confused about it, help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be honest, you can't make multiple kind of `CustomUser`. What you can do is to add multiple flags(as boolean fields) to differentiate between different kind of users

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `Group`s, and assign your users to groups. Then one can filter the users based on which group(s) that user belongs. Making multiple `CustomUser`s would be quite bad design, since it will erase all kinds of type contracts.